# PHP countdown serverside cache

Tags: php, caching, timestamp, server

Hello my dear fellow programmers.

I have a problem. I'm trying to fetch a difference between the current timestamp and an arbitrary timestamp from our database using the sever-sided language PHP, initializing a client-sided JavaScript countdown timer. However, the cache on the files makes it kind of hard.

For this demo this is what I've used

```
<html>
<head>
    <META http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
</head>

<?php
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    require_once("./config.php");
    require_once("./backend.php");
    if (!isset($_COOKIE["basket_ID"])) {
        setcookie("basket_ID", "testguid", time() + 60 * 60 * 2);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO basket(basketID, productID, quantity, GUID) VALUES (1, 1, 2, 'testguid')");
        echo "Generated cookie";
    } else {
        $temp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM basket WHERE GUID = '" . mysql_escape_string($_COOKIE["basket_ID"]) . "'");
        if (mysql_num_rows($temp) > 0) {
            $time = mysql_fetch_assoc($temp)["timestamp"];
            echo "Cookie already exists: " . $_COOKIE["basket_ID"] . "<br>";
            $diff = strtotime("now") - strtotime($time);
            echo "JUST NOW: " . time();
            echo "<br>Now: " . (new DateTime("now"))->getTimestamp() . "<br>Cookie start: " . (new DateTime($time))->getTimestamp();
            echo "<br>Second(s): " . $diff;
            echo "<br>Positive second(s): " . abs($diff);
            echo "<br>Random: " . rand();
        }
    }
?>

</html>
```

But when a visitor refreshes the page quickly, the numbers stay the samme. Only if you press CTRL + F5 or use similar methods, to force the client to get the new information and force the client to drop the cache.

So I was wondering! Is there anyone out there, who might be more imaginative than me, and want to help me in this course?

I am open to suggestions on how I might solve this problem of mine.

Thank you for reading this. (and of course for trying to help)

Comment: Have you tried adding `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">` to your page's <head> section?

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I have tried every method from earth to the building limit in minecraft.. And nothing seems to work when trying to prevent the client to make a cache :/ But thanks anyway :)

Comment: Then I'm afraid that your server side code is to blame. Web browsers check whether the output has changed and will cache it only if it doesn't. It is very common to see CSS and images cached, but I have never really encountered a persistent plain text cache. Are you using any server side cache? For example WordPress WP-cache or similar? Could you paste in your HTML/JS?

Comment: I followed the link but I keep getting "headers already sent" warning and "Generated cookie" info. Nothing changes when I reload the page.

Comment: @TomaszCz. yeah.. I can see that... that is odd.. gimme a sec

Comment: For the sake of this example, remove everything that's above php opening tag `<?php` This includes HTML code, white space, line breaks and so on. This will mend the "headers already sent" error and will allow cookies to be set.

Comment: @TomaszCz. yes I have done that now :) It should be working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your server response headers, your server is using [Varnish cache](https://www.varnish-cache.org/). Putting your application on a different server that you are sure is NOT using any caching should help.

From what [Varnish forum says](https://www.varnish-cache.org/forum/topic/818) there's no simple way of disabling Varnish from .htaccess so you should contact the server administrator asking them to disable Varnish for your account.

As for reference, here is a topic on diabling Varnish from stackoverflow: [How to disable Varnish Cache from within a PHP script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954657/how-to-disable-varnish-cache-from-within-a-php-script)

Comment: Thank you very much! :) Have a nice one!